# Convert jQuery serializeArray method function to vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, serialization

I am using the jQuery serializeArray method to create an array of objects from a form, but the form already outputs an object. How would I rewrite this to vanilla JavaScript?

```
e.serializeArray().map(x=>{
  let cookie_val = Cookies.get(x.name)
    if (cookie_val && cookie_val != ''){
      e.find('input[name="'+x.name+'"]').val(cookie_val).change();
    }
})
```

Comment: "How would I rewrite this to vanilla JavaScript?" ... jQuery is open source. Try examining the source code to see if that gives you any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FormData`:

```js
const result = [...new FormData($form).entries()].map(([name, value]) => ({name, value}));

console.log(result);
```

```html
<form id="$form">
  <input type="text" name="text1" value="foo" />
  <input type="text" name="text2" value="bar" />
  <input type="text" name="text3" value="baz" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="check" checked />
</form>
```